# Can testNG be used to automate testing a Qt Application

Tags: qt

I have a Qt Application. I want to know whether or not i can automate the testing using TestNG. 
Do suggest, if there are any open source Automation tool available.(pls dont mention squish).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong about the qttestlib module as a testing framework for a qt application? It integrates the best with the QObject hierarchy as well, like signals, slots, etc, for which you would not have tight connection with TestNG. Are you trying to use QtJambi, or what is the reason behind?

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 0):

You should use the test module provided by Qt proper to test Qt applications, really. It integrates well with the `QObject` hierarchy like signals, slots, et al, for which you would not have tight integration with TestNG.

Please see the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html) for further details.